# Running 2 Server Then Cannot Access Resource When Cors Already Set

Tags: javascript, java, angular, rest, cors

I use 2 server in 1 PC and service already running

Server 1 :

- Rest Full with Java Spring Boot

- IP localhost:8098

- Source like this (sorry not full code)

```
    @CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://10.100.0.207","http://localhost"}) @RequestMapping(value = "/getfiles", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public Map<String, ArrayList<String>> getFiles() {
    return  fullContent;
}
```

Server 2 :

- Using web service xampp

- file name testangular.html

- IP localhost

- Source like this (sorry not full code)

```
<div ng-controller="getFiles">
<ul ng-repeat="x in getdata.files">
    <li>{{x}}</li>
</ul></div> app.controller('getFiles', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://localhost:8098/getfiles").then(function (response){
    $scope.getdata = response.data;
        });
    });
```

A both service running success in my local PC with http://localhost/testangular.html because i set Cors in java

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://10.100.0.207","http://localhost"})
```

Now i connected 2 PC with same Wifi and running from different PC with http://10.100.0.207/testangular.html i cannot get data from server 1 (RestFull) but when i running http://10.100.0.207/testangular.html in PC server i got all data

10.100.0.207 is my local ip wifi where 2 service installed

can someone explain why i cannot get data from server 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking to your configuration you are missing the port in `origins` (origins = {"http://10.100.0.207:8098","http://localhost:8098"})) you can also just do all domains what is the default `@CrossOrigin`

Comment: sorry, sir i edit question
i cannot get data from server 1(my java restfull) in server 2(call api) is success

Comment: Did you hard coded `$http.get("http://localhost:8098/getfiles")` because this will only work on 1 pc the one that has `http://localhost:8098/getfiles` running

Comment: yes sir, i understand know thx, i change to 10.100.0.207:8098